# MS Access Gray box appears when clicking Report background

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

When I click on the background of my Report, I get this gray box that covers the entire form.

It goes away when I click inside any of the controls, but wanted to know how to turn off this function or disable the gray box from appearing when someone clicks on the background of the Report.

See images below as an example.

[image]
[image]

Is this normal for all reports, or is it an F4 setting, etc?  Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is that region? Detail? Form header/footer? Page header/footer? Please provide a screenshot more showing full report. And why are you using button controls on reports and not forms?

Comment: That is a small section of the entire Report, it is not in the Header nor Footer, but in the Detail section.  The full report is not much larger than that screenshot, and contains just those two buttons and a few controls that get populated from From1.  I originally attempted to put the print and save buttons ON a Form, but everything I read said that you have to print a PDF directly from the Report, and not a Form, so I  threw the buttons on the Report itself.  Form1 populates the data and opens the Report in question.

Comment: *I read said that you have to print a PDF directly from the Report, and not a Form* ... not true. You can call `DoCmd.OutputTo` *anywhere* in forms, reports, macros, modules, even outside MS Access (like in Excel or Python) but still calling the Access library!

Comment: Can you still post a wider lens screenshot? Is the entire Detail section grayed or a box inside Detail? I cannot tell from here.

Comment: Yes, this is normal. Since those controls are in Detail section and report is apparently in ReportView, that highight indicates record is selected. Don't use ReportView.

Comment: I was able to get everything working on the Form, versus the Report as suggested - just wanted to follow up and confirm it worked for others out there.